# Laundering between different jurisdictions

Tags: criminal-law, is-x-legal

Is money laundered outside the U.S. in a country with which the U.S. does not have an extradition treaty illegal in the U.S.? In this matter, I do not mean that a country will ask the United States to somehow return the person for committing a crime in their jurisdiction, but that whether this money will be illegal in the United States if a criminal case is not initiated in the jurisdiction where the money was laundered.

I would be grateful if you could refer to specific laws in your reply.

Answer (score 2):

"Money" doesn't go to prison.

Using money whose source has been concealed in the U.S. is what the crime of money laundering is. Money hasn't been laundered until you try to pass it off as having a source different than it actually has. *See* [18 U.S. Code § 1956](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1956).

This statute also asserts extraterritorial jurisdiction over foreign money launderers for purposes of civil actions to seize property belonging to them.

Comment: I assume that “money” can mean a rich person is not the intended meaning. Although, by and large, that kind of money doesn’t go to prison either.

Comment: @DaleM The first sentence of this answer refers to "whether this money will be illegal in the United States" in the question.